# delete single record in salesforce by php

Tags: php, php-toolkit

I have to delete a single record based on id but I got

> error bad id 2 Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array (
>   [0] => stdClass Object ( [message] => bad id 2 [statusCode] =>
>   MALFORMED_ID ) ) [id] => [success] => ) )

```
<?php
    require_once('userAuth.php');

    require_once ('soapclient/SforcePartnerClient.php');

    $mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
    $mySforceConnection->createConnection("PartnerWSDL.xml");
    $mySforceConnection->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD.SECURITY_TOKEN);
    $ids=array();
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    array_push($ids, $id);
    print_r($deleteResult);
    $deleteResult = $mySforceConnection->delete($ids);
?>
```

Comment: Well, what was the Id value you passed the API? Was it in fact a Malformed ID?

Comment: It was id 2 that i am getting through http://localhost/SFDC/delete.php?id=2

Comment: '2' is not a valid Salesforce 15 or 18-character Id. Are you trying to use an External Id field? Would you please edit your question to provide more context?

Comment: yes i am using external id which is auto number field

Answer (score 1):

The [`delete()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_delete.htm) SOAP API call does not accept external Ids. It requires valid Salesforce Ids.

To delete a record based on its External Id, you need to first perform a [`query()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_query.htm) to locate the Id(s) for the record(s) with that External Id value, then pass those Ids to `delete()`.

Comment: can you provide sample code to delete external id of salesforce record in php ?

Comment: No. I'm not a PHP programmer.

Comment: can you provide some hint how to to do this because i don't want to pass external ids i want to delete only one record at a time based on single external id

Comment: Resolved the issue by giving salesforce id